# Conditional formatting, one Column based on another

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Cells in column A will contain dates. There will be dates in column B as well. I need the cells in column B to turn red if the date is after that of column A.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take a minute to read ***[ask]***, then update your question with details of what you have attempted and researched so far?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting is what you are looking for.

[image: Conditional formatting]

You can find it under Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine. The standard formula for comparison is:

```
=$A1>$B1
```

After that you can click on the Format button and define the color for highlighting under Fill. Once done you can define selection of cells that this formula applies to in the Rules Manager.

[image: Current Selection]

You can download the file that I worked on here:

https://app.box.com/shared/static/9xy8nvilkrmfvbandg8wfihvimx360j9.xlsx

Explore conditional formatting further at:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/

http://blogs.office.com/2013/04/04/using-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-dates-in-excel/